# Setting the language of time axes of a zoo object in R

Tags: r, time, plot, time-series, zoo

I'm working on a zoo object in R containing a financial time series and wanted to plot it.

By using the simple command

```
plot(zoo_obj)
```

a plot is automatically created as in the figure below. How to choose the language of the x-axis?

Here the x-axis is in Italian and I wanted to have that in English.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These work for me:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "French")
```

etc. on a Windows 8.1 "R version 3.0.2 Patched (2013-11-25 r64299)" system.